# Send both characters and bytes via sockets(TCP)

Tags: java, sockets

I made multiclient chat that is working pretty well. I am sending data through `PrintWriter` and receiving them using `BufferedReader`. As far as they are characters everything goes fine. But I though about adding possibility to send voice, too. And here I faced the problem. I have already used socket input and output stream and using them for transmitting characters. How to solve this problem and make sending bytes also possible? Isn't possible to create second stream that would be responsible for transmitting bytes? It would make things much more easier . If not how to solve it otherway?

Comment: Switch to byte[] even for ASCII content. You can easily convert String back and forth byte [].

Answer (score 0):

I would not use TCP for voice transmitting, see the differences between TCP and UDP.

However, you can mix it by sending bytes only and converting all char-messages to byte-messages? I would not mix the writers streams.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I'd simply open another socket.
Since you're considering VoIP, you might want to consider a UDP socket instead of TCP (assuming you use TCP for your chat).

But remember that in the end you always send bytes over a socket; it doesn't matter if it's text or voice data; text strings are also converted to bytes.